# Whats the wrong in this code?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html

Hi everyone I am a new to jQuery. While learning I am following this link: 
http://api.jquery.com/browser/. When I am trying to do this example in VS 2010 I'm not getting the exact output. But when I was copying the code which is in this link I was getting the correct output. Please could any one help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <base href="http://docs.jquery.com" />
        <title>index(subject) function</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .div_style
            {
                background-color: Aqua;
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: small;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.js" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("div.div_style").click(function () {

                    //This is the DOM element clicked
                    var index = $("div").index(this);
                    $("span").text("That was div index #" + index);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span></span>
        <br />
        <div class="div_style ">
            First Div
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="div_style ">
            Second Div
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="div_style ">
            Third Div
        </div>
        <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What hs VS got to do with this? It is an html page is it not?

Comment: Yes ofcourse ,as am doing this example in VS .I have mentioned that also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use self closing tags for `<script>`. You must end with a `</script>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot .your are superb.